# Linux Mint VM in VirtualBox freezes with DISKFULL error

Tags: linux, unix, virtualbox, partitioning, operating-systems

[Disk partitioning guide for Linux Mint Debian](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2010/09/18/disk-partitioning-guide-for-linux-mint-debian/2/)

This guides shows me how to partition my HD for Linux Mint. I'm trying to install Mint as a guest client on Windows 7 hosted VirtualBox. I used to let it freely partition my allocated space (80GB) but Mint always fails when I try to update or install any large software from the command prompt or update manager.

The error is `DISKFULL` and the OS hangs, therefore I have to power it off/forcefully shut it down.

Later on, I fail to boot it up again. It freezes. An error is displayed from the kernel stating that I need to upgrade or change the current BIOS; At this point Linux Mint is screwed up.

I have no idea how to bring it back. I always have to reinstall the OS and currently I am looking for information that helps me partition the HD myself. The link above helps, but I am thinking there are several places in Linux partitions (folders) that I need to divide my HD, while the above explanation only offers me 4 divisions (where are others, i.e. `/var`, `/etc`, `/mnt`, etc. ?).

Comment: I'm not sure if custom-partitioning the installation is the solution you're looking for. It'd help to troubleshoot the actual problem, and therefore you should give us more info about your VM, e.g. the output of `df -h`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Linux Mint 32 or 64 bit?  I know I had some issues with the x64 Mint when not enough memory is allocated.  Is your Windows 7 box a Intel or AMD?  I had an issue with not having some BIOS setting setup to correctly run the VM.  Also, what format are you formatting the drive in?  This could play a part in some of the problems.  Please provide more information so we can better help you.

Comment: Thank you, i resolve my own problem, it was just a very basic thing I didn't notice. My drive was FAT32 formatted, and that is the only cause for all such a problem